# Can I apply experience on naive actor critic directly? Should it work?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, experience-replay

Can I apply experience replay on naive actor-critic directly? Should it work?

I have tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18038/1794, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120777/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. I absolutely see no problem in posting a question on multiple sites if the question is on-topic on those sites.

Comment: So I only received answers telling me that I cross posted the question without getting any real answers addressing this question :(